# Make meteor client ignore a specific node module whereas server should use it

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, meteor-clt

I have used this module in my library https://www.npmjs.com/package/chilkat_win32 I tried using this library in my meteor project. But when I run I get the following error.

```
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR) C:\Users\macilamanym\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)                                           throw(ex);
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)                                                 ^
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR) G:\Projects\Kube 2.0\edge-node-sdk-typescript\edge-node-sdk-js-examples\edge-node-sdk-meteor-example\simple-todos\node_modules\edge-node-sdk-js\node_modules\chilkat_win32\chilkat.node
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Projects\Kube 2.0\edge-node-sdk-typescript\edge-node-sdk-js-examples\edge-node-sdk-meteor-example\simple-todos\node_modules\edge-node-sdk-js\lib\main\EdgeNode.js:9:15)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W20160616-12:38:10.272(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Projects\Kube 2.0\edge-node-sdk-typescript\edge-node-sdk-js-examples\edge-node-sdk-meteor-example\simple-todos\node_modules\edge-node-sdk-js\lib\index.js:2:18)
```

I understand that this can only be run in server side and not client side. But how can I make it work only with the meteor server and make meteor client ignore it? Any help would be much appreciated.